# Nested Recycle view using a Parent list inside a Child List and remove all data Child list and remove a parent list position in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, view, nested, recycle

Nested Recycle view using a Parent list inside a Child List and remove all data Child list and remove a parent list position in android kotlin ?

Nested Recycle using a Parent Array inside a child array and data exit one data and remove one data  than both remove a parent array element number one and child element number one both ?